# How to constrain type parameter to structs that embed another struct?

Tags: go, generics

Given the current type parameter [proposal](https://go.googlesource.com/proposal/+/refs/heads/master/design/43651-type-parameters.md) (I don't expect it to change significantly) I want to write an interface constraint that limits struct types to those that embed another struct.

The idea is:

```
type Base struct {}

type Foo struct { Base }

type Bar struct { Base; s string }

type Baz struct { s string }

func fn[T HasBase](v T) {
    // ...
}
```

The `fn` function should be instantiated with `Foo` and `Bar` but not with `Baz`. The purpose would be to access `Base` (and its fields) from the function body, and possibly enforcing some particular type composition in API design.

I could try with the following:

```
type HasBase interface {
    ~struct{ Base }
}
```

where `HasBase` is defined as the type set of types whose underlying type is `struct{ Base }`.

Given that the underlying type of a struct literal [is itself](https://go.dev/ref/spec#Types), this `HasBase` allows `Foo` but not `Bar`.

I could add `Bar`'s underlying type to the constraint:

```
type HasBase interface {
    ~struct{ Base } | ~struct{ Base; s string }
}
```

But this is not scalable. I need to match the structs definitions literally, even the field names must match. Even worse, although the proposal hints that the above is possible, it was actually [left out of the implementation](https://github.com/golang/go/issues/48522).

So based on the linked issue I can use the following workaround, i.e. declare a method on the `Base` type (possibly unexported) and throw that into the type constraint:

```
func (b Base) getBase() Base { return b }

type HasBase interface {
    getBase() Base
}
```

which isn't much different than using `HasBase` as a simple non-constraint interface (!!) and forgo generics — probably differing only in interface boxing of non-pointer types?

```
// also works, and also gives access to the getBase() method
func fn2(t HasBase) {
    // ...
}
```

Am I missing something obvious, or is this actually the only way to do this as of today?

GoTip playground: https://gotipplay.golang.org/p/_SlZlnDL1dE

Comment: _"The purpose would be to access Base (and its fields) from the function body."_ Then `fn()` should take a value of `Base` simply.

Comment: @icza true actually, although I envision the constraint could be useful for enforcing some particular type composition in API design

Comment: Reading through the proposal, I don't think you're missing anything. Primary design of constraints is to restrict the type set for specific operations, having a field in a struct does not fall under this category.